# Android Draw bouncing circles on touch

Tags: android, multithreading, touch-event

Recently i've tried to make an app similar to a java project I made a long ago. It draws a circle with random color everytime I click a button, and move it through the window.

I have two clases: one for the thread an one for the UI. In the UI, I handle the click events and create a thread for every circle like this:

```
Hilo Carrete = new Hilo();
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == Circulo) {

        Carrete = new Hilo(100, 200, "C");
        add(Carrete);
        repaint();

    }
```

"Hilo" is my thread class and Circulo the text of the button.

I want to make something similar in android with onTouchEvent but I don't know how I do the "add(Carrete)" in android. How can I add a new thread to a view?

This is my source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Hilo vista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(vista);
    vista = new Hilo(this);

    vista.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            float X = event.getX();
            float Y = event.getY();

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                v.postInvalidate();
                v.draw(new Canvas().drawCircle(X, Y, 30, ););

            }

            return true;

        }
    });

}

class Hilo extends View implements Runnable {

    Thread hilo;
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 0;
    int colorPelota;
    int Xmax, Ymax;
    boolean horizontal, vertical;
    Random colores;
    //Color colorFigura;
    Paint fondo, bolita;

    public Hilo(Context contexto) {

        super(contexto);

        fondo = new Paint();
        bolita = new Paint();
        colores = new Random();

        int r = colores.nextInt(255);
        int g = colores.nextInt(255);
        int b = colores.nextInt(255);
        colorPelota = Color.rgb(r, g, b);

        fondo.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        bolita.setColor(colorPelota);

        if(Math.random() <= 0.5) {horizontal = true;}
        else {horizontal = false;}

        if(Math.random() <= 0.5) {vertical = true;}
        else {vertical = false;}

        hilo = new Thread(this);
        hilo.start();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawPaint(fondo);
        canvas.drawCircle(X, Y, 30, bolita);
        this.draw(new Canvas().drawCircle(););
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {

            try{

                if(X == 50) horizontal = false;

                else if(X >= Xmax) horizontal = true;

                if(Y == 50) vertical = false;

                else if(Y >= Ymax) vertical = true;

                if((horizontal == false) && (vertical == false)) {

                    X++;
                    Y--;

                }

                else if((horizontal == false) && (vertical == true)) {

                    X++;
                    Y++;

                }

                else if((horizontal == true) && (vertical == false)) {

                    X--;
                    Y--;

                }

                else if((horizontal == true) && (vertical == true)) {

                    X--;
                    Y++;

                }

                hilo.sleep(10);

            }

            catch(InterruptedException ie) {

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        X = w / 2;
        Y = 0;
        Ymax = h;
        Xmax = w;
    }

   /* @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float X = event.getX();
        float Y = event.getY();

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            postInvalidate();

        }

        return true;

    }*/
}
```

Thanks in advance.